# If I delete and then re-create my one-and-only VM, can I reuse the same Windows 10 activation key I used the first time?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, vmware-player

I've obtained a Windows 10 activation key specifically for my one-and-only VM. If I subsequently delete that VM and then re-create it from scratch -- either on the same machine or a different machine -- can I reuse that same key?

(I'm using VMWare Workstation Player. My OS on both the host machine and the VM is Windows 10 Home.)

Comment: "Can I reuse that same key?" - Yes

Comment: As Ramhound says the answer should be simply "yes" but there may be some time based limit between activations. If you installed the VM 6 months ago then you're probably fine, but if you reinstalled it 3 times in the last week then you may have to contact Microsoft to get the limit reset. The exact figures and time frames will be known only to Microsoft.

Comment: Windows 10 - you can just do an in-=place Windows 10 Reset. Works for virtual machines as well. And that does not count against reinstalls if they would be frequent.

Comment: As @Mokubai points out.. if you CALL Microsoft, they will help you out no problem.  They keys are there to stop mass piracy, not a legit individual user.

Comment: @John said, "you can just do an in-=place Windows 10 Reset." How do I do that?

Comment: Windows Updates, Additional Options, Recovery - Reset is there.

Comment: Awesome, thanks all!